# creating jenkins container by docker

Tags: docker, jenkins

I wanna create jenkins container by docker.
what I have done is

1.create jenkins container by Kitematic.

2.unlock jenkins

3.customize  jenkins (install suggest plugin)

4.Create First Admin User
stock here after input username and password

here is the exception.

btw.

1.this happened when I create jenkins for the second time.
The first time is ok without exception.
2.if I don`t install any plugin , it will run without exception.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkt2W.jpg

> INFO: Completed initialization Nov 02, 2017 6:11:44 AM
>   hudson.PluginManager dynamicLoad INFO: Plugin email-ext:2.61
>   dynamically installed Nov 02, 2017 6:11:44 AM
>   hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run INFO: Installation
>   successful: Email Extension Plugin Nov 02, 2017 6:11:44 AM
>   hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run INFO: Starting the
>   installation of Mailer Plugin on behalf of admin Nov 02, 2017 6:11:44
>   AM hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob _run INFO: Skipping
>   duplicate install of: Mailer Plugin@1.20 Nov 02, 2017 6:11:44 AM
>   hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob run INFO: Installation
>   successful: Mailer Plugin Nov 02, 2017 6:13:07 AM
>   hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler$1 reportException
>   WARNING: null java.io.IOException: finished at
>   com.jcraft.jzlib.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:90)
>   at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.FilterServletOutputStream.write(FilterServletOutputStream.java:26)
>   at
>   hudson.util.HttpResponses$JSONObjectResponse.generateResponse(HttpResponses.java:181)
>   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.handleHttpResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:124)
>   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponseRenderer$Default.generateResponse(HttpResponseRenderer.java:69)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.renderResponse(Function.java:136) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:119)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:129) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$3.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:209) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:58)
>   at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:715) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:845) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:649) at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:238) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
>   at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:135)
>   at jenkins.install.SetupWizard$1.doFilter(SetupWizard.java:530) at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:132)
>   at
>   hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:138)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>   at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:80) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
>   at
>   hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:51)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   jenkins.security.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:117)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:142)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:92)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
>   at
>   hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:90)
>   at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>   at
>   hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>   at
>   org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
>   at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
>   at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
>   at
>   winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

I have ever faced the same issue like you when i deploy container in docker swarm when i choose `Install suggested plugins`, but try to choose `Select plugins to install`, it works for me